# Vaadin CRUD UI for related entities

Tags: java, user-interface, view, orm, vaadin

How to display UI part for related entities?

If I have such grid for Product entity

```
    GridCrud<T> crud = new GridCrud<T>(tClass);
    crud.getCrudFormFactory().setUseBeanValidation(true);
    crud.setFindAllOperation(() -> (Collection<T>)repository.findAll());
    crud.setAddOperation(repository::save);
    crud.setUpdateOperation(repository::save);
    crud.setDeleteOperation(repository::delete);
```

And Product is next

```
public class Product {//...
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "optionToProduct",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "optionId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "productId")})
private Set<Option> options = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How to show list of Options for each Product during editing?

Vaadin

```
    <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.crudui</groupId>
        <artifactId>crudui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Which Vaadin version do you apply?

Comment: added to the question body

Answer (score 0):

GridCrud is not a class that is available in Vaadin per default, so either you are using an add-on or custom code from your team. Can you check where it comes from? It would make it easier for others to help you.

I’m not sure what `grid.getCrudFormFactory()` returns, but it sounds like the correct place to configure these. Ie. formFactory.addField(field, component); or something similar.

Comment: It is addon, added to the question body.